# Как решить проблему с резким изменением высоты у RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня в верстке в LinearLayout есть RecyclerView, под которым находится еще один элемент. Проблема заключается в том, что когда в RecyclerView добавляются/удаляются элементы его "физическая" высота меняется мгновенно (ну или просто так выглядит, а причина в другом), хотя (стандартная) анимация еще только началась. Если с добавлением это выглядит терпимо, то при удалении элемента за счет резко изменившейся высоты, элемент, который был под RecyclerView поднимается вверх также резко, в то время как анимация сдвига элементов RecyclerView еще проигрывается => нижний элемент RecyclerView выезжает из под элемента находящегося под RecyclerView.
Я знаю только один вариант решения данной проблемы - сделать элемент под RecyclerView его частью, тогда анимация будет работать и на него. Но, на мой взгляд, подобное решение не всегда уместно.
Есть ли какой-то иной путь решения данной проблемы?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="80"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_base"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_vertical_edit_text"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_base"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_vertical_edit_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextPrimary" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="text"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Установка менеджера и адаптера

```
    recyclerSubtasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerSubtasks.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Сам адаптер использует SortedList

Разметка элемента списка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_base"
        android:button="@drawable/item_check_box" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_subtask"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_base"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:hint="Enter title"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_vertical_edit_text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_base"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_vertical_edit_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_cross"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox_done"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_cross"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_check_box_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_check_box_icon"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_base"
        android:src="@drawable/cross"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: может покажете какой-то код? разметку например, добавление как происходит, так сложно понять где именно вам нужна помощь

Comment: Добавил код верстки

Comment: как-то все у вас сложно)) почему нельзя scrollView сделать корневым элементом? так же добавьте `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` так как он в другом скролле находится

Comment: За recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); спасибо, буду знать, но проблему это не решает. scrollView не корневой так как это не вся верстка, я из нее убрал некоторые элементы, которые никак не влияют на проблему.

Comment: добавьте разметку элемента списка если таковая используется

Comment: Есть, добавил..

Comment: а зачем вы при сеттинге layoutManager-a переопределяете функцию скролла?

Comment: Это было нужно, чтобы скрол не дублировался (внешний и скрол recycler-а). Хотя сейчас убрал и скрол все равно не дублируется как раньше (т.к. recycler обернут в RelativeLayout). Но это не связано с проблемой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте установить для вашего списка фиксированный размер:

```
setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))
recyclerSubtasks.hasFixedSize()
```

и так же установите такой `LayoutManager`

Comment: Это частично решает проблему, но список должен динамически изменятся (по нажатию кнопок могут добавляться и убираться элементы), т.е. он не может иметь фиксированный размер

Comment: добавляется и удаляется все через адаптер

Comment: Да, но высота recycler-а останется фиксированной, т.е. появится внутренний скрол, до тех пор пока не произойдет "перестройка" интерфейса (не знаю как правильно это называется, но она происходит, например, при появлении клавиатуры), после чего высота изменится, чтобы все элементы убрались. А мне надо, чтобы все элементы были единым списком. Видимо recycler не предназначен для подобных махинаций, и надо просто все элементы засунуть в один recycler. Но спасибо, что пытались помочь